# Relationship error EF Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-relationship

This is the relationship i need to create
[image: This is my relationship i have to create]

And i already have the entity class for each one, the "Cuentas" class is:

```
  public class Cuenta 
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Perfil> Perfiles { get; set; }
    }
```

"Perfiles" class is:

```
  public class Perfil : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }


        public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }

        public int CuentaId { get; set; }
        public Cuenta Cuenta { get; set; }

    }
```

And finally

```
 public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        public bool Activo { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UltimoLogin { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }

        public int? UsuarioCreacion { get; set; }

        public int? UsuarioModificacion { get; set; }

        public int CuentaID { get; set;}

        public Cuenta Cuenta { get; set; }

        public int PerfilID { get; set; }

        public Perfil Perfil{ get; set; }
    }
```

Everything its okey at this moment, but when im trying to update the database with the EF Core command, the error message i get is:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint **'FK_Usuarios_Perfiles_PerfilID'** on
>   table **'Usuarios'** may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

I'm not sure if the diagram relationship it's the best practice or i'm baddly creating the relationship in entityframework.

Comment: The posted diagram clearly shows the cycle/multiple cascade path from `Cuenta` to `Usuario`. `CuentaID` in `Usuario` is redundant.

Comment: I saw the same thing as you, to be clear you think to fix this error we need to remove the relationship between those two (Cuenta,Usuario)?

Comment: Indeed. Clienta 1 -> M Perfile 1 -> M Usuario should be enough. In case that's what you need (I can't follow exactly the Spanish terminology here :))

Comment: Excelent, I would need to talk with the designer in this case. Thanks Iván